# Having issues getting images centered properly inside of square container

Tags: css, html, sass, slick.js

I'm working on a redesign of my photography site and am setting up a simple slider for some of my photos. I'm having issues getting the images to be centered in divs with padding all around. I'm trying to mimic how photos look on my [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/joe_scotto/) where they're centered in a square but keep their aspect ratio.

Here is a [link](https://codepen.io/Joe_Scotto/pen/pLvdRj) to my Codepen.

Example of what I'm going for: [image]

SCSS:

```
.slick-slider {
  .image_container {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 256px;
    padding: 20px;

    img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; bottom: 0; 
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-height: 300px;
      left: 0; right: 0;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slick-slider">
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="http://cdn.jscotto.com/sites/joescottophotography.com/images/portraits/photo-portraits-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="http://cdn.jscotto.com/sites/joescottophotography.com/images/portraits/photo-portraits-2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Easiest way is to make sure all images are the same size, cropped, before you load them to the slider.

Comment: Your codepen, and the "what I'm going for" image; to me both look like the images are centered the same way. The codepen looks it does what you are trying to do. I'm not sure what is being asked

Comment: @chiliNUT That's because I ended up figuring it out, Going to post the answer now. The code that is here on SO is the original non-working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up messing around with it for a little while and figured out the correct css:

```
.image_container {
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 350px;
  background: rgba($offBlack, 0.05);

  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 310px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it automatically crops and fit to the div

```css
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.thumbnail img.portrait {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://cdn.jscotto.com/sites/joescottophotography.com/images/portraits/photo-portraits-5.jpg" alt="Image" />
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://cdn.jscotto.com/sites/joescottophotography.com/images/portraits/photo-portraits-2.jpg" class="portrait" alt="Image" />
</div>
```